# How to deal with resource leak problem in scanner class

Tags: java

The code below gets name and age of the animal and displays it. When I give 1 for dogs, for the first time the code runs correctly and when I give 1 for second time, i.e. when count is changed to 2, the code gets only the age and skips the name.

This happens for both `Dog` and `Cat` classes. And also the IDE shows that there is a resource leak problem near the `Scanner scan`. Please give me a solution

NOTE: This is the first time I'm programming in java, so I can't explain the problem clearly. So please excuse my flaws.

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package pets;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Karthic Kumar
 *
 */
public class pets {

public static int total = 0;

public class Dog
{
int age;
String name;
int serial_no=1;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public void get_name()
{   
    System.out.println("enter the name of the dog: ");
    name = scan.nextLine(); 
}

public void get_age()
{
    System.out.println("enter the age of the dog: ");
    age = scan.nextInt();   
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(serial_no+". the name of the dog is "+ name +" and his age is "+ age+"\n");
}

public void total_display()
{
    System.out.println("total animals = "+total);
}
}

public class Cat
{
int age;
String name;
int serial_no=1;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public void get_name()
{   
    System.out.println("enter the name of the cat: ");
    name = scan.nextLine(); 
}

public void get_age()
{
    System.out.println("enter the age of the cat: ");
    age = scan.nextInt();   
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(serial_no+". the name of the dog is "+ name +" and his age is "+ age);
}

}




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        int type,count=1;
        pets object_1 = new pets();

        pets.Dog dog = object_1.new Dog();

        pets.Cat cat = object_1.new Cat();

        System.out.println("press one for dog and two for cat and 3 for total");

        while(count<=10)
        {
    System.out.println("\n"+count+". ");    



    type = scan.nextInt();

    if(type == 1)
    {
    dog.get_name();
    dog.get_age();
    dog.display();

    dog.serial_no +=1;

    pets.total+=1;

    }

    if(type == 2)
    {
    cat.get_name();
    cat.get_age();
    cat.display();

    cat.serial_no+=1;
    pets.total+=1;

    }

    if(type==3)
    {
        dog.total_display();
    }


    if(type <=4 && type >=100)
    {
        System.out.println("enter correctly");
    }

count++;
}

}

}
```

Comment: You should also post the class definition for the objects you are instantiating.

Comment: _the IDE shows that there is a resource leak_ The IDE is telling you that you need to `close()` the `Scanner`. You can ignore this because you are creating a `Scanner` for reading from _stdin_ (the standard input, i.e. the keyboard) and you should ___never___ close the standard input.

Comment: The code you posted is not a [mcve]. It would help me to help you if you posted the code for class `Pets`. It also makes it a lot easier for others to read your code if you use [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Now I have attached the full code that contains class definition. Now please give a look

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your problem, you simply need to add a call to method `nextLine()` of class `Scanner` in your `get_age()` method in both class `Cat` and class `Dog`.

Here is the entire `get_age()` method from class `Dog` with the required addition.

```java
public void get_age() {
    System.out.println("enter the age of the dog: ");
    age = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); // I added this line.
}
```